# Linear functions - Input ordering implies output ordering

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, self-learning

Let $f(x,\theta)$ be a linear function of $\theta$, meaning $f(x,\theta) = \theta^\top x$, where $\theta$ is a vector or matrix and $x$ is a vector. Is it the case that

$$
\|\theta_1\| \leq \|\theta_2\| \implies \|f(x, \theta_1)\| \leq  \|f(x, \theta_2)\|\;?
$$

I thought I could prove this using the Cauchy-Schwartz theorem $\|\theta^\top x\| \leq \|\theta^\top\|\|x\|$ but got stuck. Assuming $\|\theta_1\| \leq \|\theta_2\|$ I get $\|\theta_1^\top x\| \leq \|\theta_1^\top\|\|x\|$ and $\|\theta_2^\top x\| \leq \|\theta_2^\top\| \|x\|$. From which I get $\|\theta_1^\top x\|\leq \|\theta_2^\top\|\|x\|$. How do I then get $\|\theta_1^\top x\| \leq \|\theta_2^\top x\|$?

Hints are appreciated.

Comment: please can you define what is $X$

Comment: Thank you, I have now changed my formulation.

Comment: There are many choices of the norm $\|\theta\|$ on a matrix $\theta$. For example, the "max" norm is useful, which is the largest absolute value of an entry of $\theta$. What norm are you choosing?

Comment: I'm particularly interested in the case where $\theta$ is a vector but I was thinking that the proposition might be true for any norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no".  A counter example is if $ x $ is in the null space of $ \theta_2 $ but not of $ \theta_1 $.

Comment: How about the case when $\theta$ is a vector?

Comment: A vector is merely a special case of a matrix.  If $ x $ is orthogonal to $ \theta_2 $...   BTW, I should have said "if $ x $ is in the null space of $ \theta_2^T $".